# Brief Kafka Partition Description (i'm confused)

Tags: apache-kafka, partition

If I create a topic over x partitions, and then send 500 bits of data, numbered 1 to 500, I'd hoped to get the data back in the order I sent it. this ONLY happens if x is 1, i.e. a single partition. I'd rather thought partitioning was an efficiency of seeking thing, clearly I am mistaken? If x is greater than 1, IE multiple partitions, I get all the data back, but one partitions worth at a time...which is no good to me. Obviously, the data comes back in offset order within each partition, but the order of the data is not in the 1 to 500 it was produced at in the first place. So, brief explanation of where my thinking is going awry, or should I just stick to single partitions so my order is preserved (or implement a whole heap of sorting after I get some data back which kind of defeats the object.

Answer (score 1):

I should research more. From another thread:
"Kafka only provides a total order over messages within a partition, not between different partitions in a topic"
So,  looks like its single partition only for me.